# How to reverse tether without rooting?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, internet, usb-connection-mode, reverse-tether

Want to use PC broadband connection on the phone connected via USB [no Bluetooth or wifi] to surf on the phone or install app.
The android device is running 4.0.4 and the PC running Windows 7
I dont want to **root** the phone. I've the phone driver installed.

Answer (score 2):

well i hope i am wrong about it but as far as i know there is no way to do so. 

i tried searching a method for it and wasted about a good few dozens of hours over it and kept on searching for it until i was sure that it cant be done without rooting the device. 
many youtube videos, websites and blog claim they have a method and i tried almost every one i got to know but cudn't find a working method.

hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's probably not possible, but most of the things you would do on the phone you can do on the computer and then transfer to phone. For example, app apks can be downloaded and moved and then installed.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what others say, this is in fact possible.

As I could not find any solution myself, I finally created my own app. It supports Android 4.0+ on the client side and all major desktop operating systems on the host side.

You can check the app ReverseTethering NoRoot PRO on [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free)